# debugging intelitrace file - VS has stopped working

Tags: winforms, visual-studio, debugging

I want to debug an .itrace (intelitrace) file

I open it in visual studio

I'm using Visual studio 2015 update 3

in thread list when i click on a thread and click start debugging
I get the "visual studio has stopped working" dialog

debugging this file is realy important to me

Comment: @M Oj, If you run your VS as the admin, how about the result? Could you share us a screen shot about it? Did you get any other debugging messages except the dialog? Just double-click Main Thread, and then start debugging from where the app begins, how about the result? To debug with IntelliTrace and step through code, we must have the matching source files and symbol files. Please also make sure that it was not the symbol files or source file issue.

Comment: @M Oj,Would you please share the latest information about this issue? Could you get any debugging information now?

Comment: @JackZhai-MSFT , I tried to run VS as admin and I can provide you a screenshot , no icouldn't get any other debugging messages except the dialog - i tried the main thread dbl-click but no chance ,I have  matching source files and symbol files , where should I place them?,I could debug the file with my friend PC running VS 2017

Comment: M Oj, If the same debug file, but just your Environment has this issue, I suggest you visit some debugging settings like TOOLS->Options->Debugging->General or Symbols Option.At least, we need to make sure that it was not the debugging settings issue.